# Is there a way to include data in code file in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

My Fortran code needs to read a initialize data (about 24000 real numbers) from a file. Are there any ways to put the data in the code so that I can avoid accessing the filesystem?

I tried to use a module and put all the data into a variable initialization like this:

```
 real(kind=8) :: a(24000)=(/&
 & 1. ,&
 & 2. ,&
 ...
 &/)
```

but because of there are 24000 lines for the source file, I keep receiving compiling error "Too many continuation lines". Are there any solution to this?

Comment: Personally I have an aversion to storing large amounts of data in source files; I think the solution to your problem is to keep the data in a file and read it when the program starts.  Why do you want to avoid accessing the file system ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I hate to include data in source file too, it makes the code difficult to read and maintain. I'm trying to build a Fortran subroutine into a dynamic library, so that I can use it in other places. And I don't know wether it's possible to include data files in a dynamic library. If it's possible could you give some references? Thanks.

Comment: not that i think its a good idea, but gfortran compiles and runs this just fine. (10 X bigger even ! ) Anyone know what the standard says about allowable number of continuation lines?

Comment: Fortran 2003 increased the number of continuation lines to 255.  Fortran 95 was 39.  This is what compilers are required to support.  They can support more.

Comment: I too think that it is better to read a file for this much data.  In the Fortran code you can find the file via an environment variable so that the file doesn't have to be placed in a specific directory, nor does the user have to run the program in a specific directory.  This means that the user has to be instructed in how to setup the environment variable, or its creation is made part of the build process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`DATA`](http://www.idris.fr/data/cours/lang/fortran/F77.html#p7.3.1) statements for this.

The fact that you can "slice" up your array into sections (such as setting `a[1..100]` in one section, `a[101..200]` in the next and so on) means that you should be able to avoid the massive-statement-size problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

For such a large amount of data I would use some script language (or even Fortran) to generate a chunk of simple Fortran code like

```
a(1) = ..
a(2) = ..
a(3) = ..
```

This code could be then copy-pasted or include-d into your source code.

Answer (score 1):

One option may be to instruct your compiler to allow unlimited line lengths
and put the whole darn thing on one line.

```
gfortran -ffree-line-length-none
```

I've verified this works. I've got a 2Mb source file with just 3 lines

```
real(kind=8) :: a(24000)=(/ ......... /)
write(*,*)a(24000)
end
```

I wouldn't be surprised if some compiler has a practical line length limit though.

By the way gfortran does not like using a big `data` statement.
No error it just hangs (or takes a very long time )

//
Imagine that, my big `data` version actually compiled (and runs fine ) after 1.5 hours.  Why `data` is handled by the compiler so vastly differently from an initialization assignment is a good question.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous author stated you can use the data statement, but it can be time consuming to enter it into the code manually.  Is there a reason that you are apprehensive about the use of a READ statement in a do loop to read in the file?  If you can provide us with any input on the data file format we can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

It might seem to be archaic, but you could use [INCLUDE](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0580.htm). You'd need to modify your data file to have the form you gave,

```
real(8), dimension(24000) :: a=(/1.0,2.0,...24000./)
```

and then `include` it in the main program as such:

```
program main
   implicit none
   include "my_data_file.for"

   < ... >
end program main
```

You won't need to change your compilation command, your Fortran compiler will import the `include`d file on its own--so long as the included file is in the same directory.

Comment: `a=(/1.0,2.0,...24000./)` in just one line?

Comment: In one line, no. And after thinking about this a bit more (and toying with it on my computer), I think this method will not work for you. I think High Performance Mark's suggestion to just read the file in at run-time is probably going to be your best bet to get the data in (plus it's fast at ~0.01 seconds to read 24,000 data points in)